# How to conduct stack/memory overflow with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bad() {
    printf("Oh shit really bad~!\r\n");
}

void foo() {
    char overme[4] = "WOW";
    *(int*)(overme+8) = (int)bad;
}

int main() {
   foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you find a JavaScript runtime with a bug in its memory management system…

The short answer is that you can't. JavaScript doesn't let you manually manage your memory allocation.

Comment: Sometimes you say can't is just because you don't know.

Comment: A little politeness has never yet done any harm. So hold your tongue (that is, your keys). David is right on this one.

Comment: Sometimes you say can't is just because you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Recurse()
{
    Recurse();
}
```

Comment: It will only report "too much recursion"